# getting null parameter values when I send body from rest client

Tags: spring, rest

Iam getting null parameter values when i send values from rest client. But when I send Values from form(html view page) it is working fine.

Below one is my bean class.

```
 public class Home {

    private String id;
```

And I am sending values from rest client as post method.

```
{  
   "id":"10",

   "load":"true"
}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Request is coming to the controller class. but it will return all values as null .But when I am sending values from html page it is working fine. Any one can help how to get values.

When I am using @RequestBody in controller `calss, I am getting Caused by: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported` exception

Comment: How you solved this..?

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@RequestBody` should be added on  `Home homeRequest`.

This allows the controller to analyze the request's body as the object's instance itself. This is the case of a JSON request.

Otherwise it is possible to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` as an annotation of the controller which does the same as `@Controller`, but it adds implicitly to all the request mapping methods the annotation  `@RequestBody` to the inputs and `@ResponseBody` to all the response objects.

Comment: When I am using @RequestBody, I am getting Caused by: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported exception

Comment: Try using `headers = "content-type=application/json"` among the arguments of the `RequestBody` annotation